# Is it posible to generate a JSON from a web page for an iOS app?

Tags: html, ios, json

im making an iOS app for my school and i want that this app shows the same content that the webpage but im not the web admin, i want to know if its possible to generate a JSON or a xml file from the webpage or html code so i can get all that info automatically or I will have to write the JSON manually,i was thinking in some kind of RSS feed but the webpage doesn't have this function  thanks!!!

PS: I don't want to ask for the permissions from the web to my school because its a project proposal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer no. The server has to provide the JSON or XML.

Long answer yes, but then you'd would have to parse the html. Or try look for a lib that does it for you. Something like [this](http://json.fastfrag.org/).